# Xamarin Android - Can a WCF SOAP webservice use HttpClient for TLS 1.2?

Tags: wcf, soap, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I have a customer who requires TLS 1.2 for PCI compliance.  Xamarin Android does not support TLS 1.2 very well.  According to this
[Native HttpClientHandler](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_6/xamarin.android_6.1/#Native_HttpClientHandler) and this [Transport Layer Security](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/), you can either use HttpClient with their special mechanism to access the native Java support on Android 5 and higher, or you can use the ModernHttpClient.

However, WCF SOAP Webservice proxies generated with SvcUtil appear to use HttpWebRequest, and not HttpClient.

What's the recommended way to call WCF SOAP services using HttpClient (or ModernHttpClient)?  Will I have to manually write my own interfaces or can I use the proxy classes and serialize/deserialize them myself?  I'd rather not have to completely start from scratch, especially since it looks like TLS 1.2 is currently being added to Mono.

Answer (score 0):

i have used that type of service and it is working here i have share relevant code please try it.

```
 static void TryByWebRequest(string soapMethod)
        {
 XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();

            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"
                        <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                            <s:Body>
                                <" + soapMethod + @" 
                                xmlns=""your URI"" 
                                xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
                                    <InputXMLString>
                                        " +
                                    System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(inputXML)
                                    + @"                
                                    </InputXMLString>                            
                                    <OutputXMLString/>
                                </" + soapMethod + @">
                            </s:Body>
                       </s:Envelope>");


            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
}
     static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string soapMethod)
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"Your .asmx URL ");
                webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", "your URI \" + soapMethod);
                webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
                webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
                webRequest.Method = "POST";

                return webRequest;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.  Since this is a (hopefully) temporary solution, my goal was to create drop-in replacements for the Proxy-generated classes, and I got pretty close.  The key was to figure out how to use the DataContractSerializer to create a SOAP envelope to send, and deserialize the results.

I was successful with everything except for the serialization of the SOAP envelope that gets sent to the web service.  I ended up manually wrapping the XML in the `<envelope>` and `<body>` tags.  Nothing that I did could get the DataContractSerializer to create these correctly, although the Body contents were ok.  The Deserializer was able to handle the response from the web service without any problem though.  WCF services are very picky about the format of the SOAP envelope, and getting the classes annotated just right was a challenge.

For each function call, I had to create a Request object that wraps the parameters being sent to the web service, and a Response object that wraps the out parameters and the return code.

These look something like this, where the FunctionName is the name of the WCF function call that the proxys generated.

```
    // request envelope
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "FunctionName", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class FunctionName_Request
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public NameSpaceFunctionNameObject1 CallingObject1;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public NameSpaceFunctionNameObject2 CallingObject2;
    }

    // response envelope
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class FunctionName_ResponseEnvelope
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "Body", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public class FunctionName_ResponseBody
        {
            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "FunctionNameResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
            public class FunctionName_Response
            {
                [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
                public FunctionNameReturnCodes Result;

                [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
                public FunctionNameResponseObject Response;
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public FunctionName_Response FunctionNameResponse;
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public FunctionName_ResponseBody Body;
    }
```

Then, I can write a replacement function that my client code can call, which has exactly the same signature as the original Proxy-generated function.

```
    // FunctionName
    public FunctionNameReturnCodes FunctionName(out FunctionNameResponseObject Response, NameSpaceFunctionNameObject1 CallingObject1, NameSpaceFunctionNameObject2 CallingObject2)
    {
        // create the request envelope
        FunctionName_Request req = new FunctionName_Request();
        req.CallingObject1 = CallingObject1;
        req.CallingObject2 = CallingObject2;

        // make the call
        FunctionName_ResponseEnvelope resp = MakeWCFCall<FunctionName_ResponseEnvelope>(_EndpointAddress, _ServerName, req);

        // get the response object
        Response = resp.Body.FunctionName_Response.Response;

        // result
        return resp.Body.FunctionName_Response.Result;
    }
```

Finally, this is the function that actually serializes and deserializes the object into the HttpClient.  In my case, these are synchronous, but you could easily adapt this to work in the standard async case. It's template so it works with any of the proxy-generated types.

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // make a WCF call using an HttpClient object
    // uses the DataContractSerializer to serialze/deserialze the messages from the objects
    //
    // We manually add the <s:Envelope> and <s:Body> tags.  There should be a way to get
    // the DataContractSerializer to write these too, but everything I tried gave a message
    // that was not able to be procesed by the service.  This includes the Message object.
    // Deserializing works fine, but serializing did not.
    private T MakeWCFCall<T>(string strEndpoint, string strServerName, object SourceObject)
    {
        T Response = default(T);
        string strSoapMessage = "";
        string strSoapAction = "";

        // get the Soap Action by using the DataContractAttribute's name
        // start by getting the list of custom attributes.
        // there should only be the one
        object[] oaAttr = SourceObject.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false);
        if (oaAttr.Length > 0)
        {
            // iterate just in case there are more
            foreach (DataContractAttribute oAttr in oaAttr)
            {
                // make sure we got one
                if (oAttr != null)
                {
                    // this is the action!
                    strSoapAction = oAttr.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // serialize the request into a string
        // use a memory stream as the source
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // create the DataContractSerializer
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(SourceObject.GetType());

            // serialize the object into the memory stream
            ser.WriteObject(ms, SourceObject);

            // seek to the beginning so we can read back out of the stream
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // create the stream reader
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                // read the message back out, adding the Envelope and Body wrapper
                strSoapMessage = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s = ""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><s:Body>" + streamReader.ReadToEnd() + @"</s:Body></s:Envelope>";
            }
        }

        // now create the HttpClient connection
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            //specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            // add the Soap Action header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/" + strServerName + "/" + strSoapAction);

            // encode the saop message
            var content = new StringContent(strSoapMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

            // post to the server
            using (var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(strEndpoint), content).Result)
            {
                // get the response back
                var soapResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                // create a MemoryStream to use for serialization
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapResponse)))
                {
                    // create the reader
                    // set the quotas
                    XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(
                        memoryStream, 
                        Encoding.UTF8, 
                        new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() { MaxArrayLength = 5000000, MaxBytesPerRead = 5000000, MaxStringContentLength = 5000000 }, 
                        null);

                    // create the Data Contract Serializer
                    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

                    // deserialize the response
                    Response = (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        // return the response
        return Response;
    }
```

This approach allowed me to quickly write wrappers for all of my WCF service functions, and it's working well so far.